# How to sort an array of links by link?

Tags: javascript

This is interesting, [sorting links by content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420737/javscript-sort-links-by-content-that-are-inside-a-div), but how would you go about it using javascript?

Sorry, I meant: you have this:
http://stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow
http://www.google.com'>Google
and you want this:
""Google ""
""Stack Overflow ""
...the links having now been sorted into alphabetical order by link.

Comment: the answer to that question DOES use javascript!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant without jQuery.

Comment: `["Stack Overflow", "Google"].sort()` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have an array of links then an example would be

jQuery:

```
$('a').sort(function(a, b) { 
  a = a.text; b = b.text; 
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0; 
});
```

without:

```
Array().slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).sort(function(a, b) { 
  a = a.text; b = b.text; 
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0; 
});
```

Using jQuery or whatever to get an array of links

Then it sorts the text in between the a tags

Comment: Thanks very much; this works.What I did was:    `function orthis() {
    var j = [];
    t = document.getElementById('linkBox2').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0;i<t.length;i++)

    {j.push('<a href="'+t[i]+'">' + t[i].lastChild.nodeValue +'</a>');}

    j.sort(function(a, b) {

    a = a.text; b = b.text;
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
    });
    j.sort();
    document.getElementById('linkBox2').innerHTML += '<p>' +j;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this does not work :( (using some code from [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array))

```js
function sortAsc(a, b) {
  if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) return 1;
  if (a.innerHTML === b.innerHTML) return 0;
  if (a.innerHTML < b.innerHTML) return -1;
}

function sortDsc(a, b) {
  if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) return -1;
  if (a.innerHTML === b.innerHTML) return 0;
  if (a.innerHTML < b.innerHTML) return 1;
}

function $A(iterable) {
  if (!iterable) return [];
  if ('toArray' in Object(iterable)) return iterable.toArray();
  var length = iterable.length || 0,
    results = new Array(length);
  while (length--) results[length] = iterable[length];
  return results;
}


function sortLinks(containerId, dir) {
  var linksCollection = document.getElementById(containerId).getElementsByTagName('a');
  var links = $A(linksCollection)
  document.getElementById(containerId).innerHTML = links.sort(dir === "a" ? sortAsc : sortDsc).join('');
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="sort-this-div">
  <a href="http://something45yer.com">Content3</a>
  <a href="http://somethingeyerty.com">Content1</a>
  <a href="http://somethingfwegrw.com">Content2</a>
  <a href="http://somethingt43rwer.com">Content4</a>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="return sortLinks('sort-this-div','a')">Ascending</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return sortLinks('sort-this-div','d')">Descending</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  YOu just want to sort an array?

```
["Stack Overflow", "Google"].sort()
```